# ColorIndex missing after xlPasteFormats

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to have my formatting exactly retrieved as it is.
[image]

In the initial document, every 2nd row is grey, but after execution of the code below, the color is gone.

```
Sub CopyData(ByRef shSource As Worksheet, shTarget As Worksheet)

Const VHead As String = "A1:H1"
Const VMBom As String = "A2:H100"

shSource.Range(VHead).Copy
With shTarget.Range("A1")
.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats

End With


Dim lRow As Long
Dim i As Integer


lRow = shTarget.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

shSource.Range(VMBom).Copy

With shTarget.Range("A" & lRow)
.PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes
.Sort Key1:=.Columns(1), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
.WrapText = True

End With
shTarget.Columns("A").ColumnWidth = 6.11
shTarget.Columns("B").ColumnWidth = 50
shTarget.Columns("C").ColumnWidth = 50
shTarget.Columns("D").ColumnWidth = 5.44
shTarget.Columns("E").ColumnWidth = 5.89
shTarget.Columns("F").ColumnWidth = 9
shTarget.Columns("G").ColumnWidth = 21.22
shTarget.Columns("H").ColumnWidth = 10.89
shTarget.Rows.EntireRow.AutoFit

For i = 2 To lRow Step 2
shTarget.Range("A:E").ColorIndex = 15
Next


' Reset the clipboard.
Application.CutCopyMode = xlCopy
```

End Sub

I tried to make a loop every 2nd row and reapply the missing COlorIndex, but I am getting an error:

> Object doesn't support this property or method

Is there any way of how could I transfer the formatting in 100% correctly?

UPDATE:

After applying the following code:

```
 For i = 3 To lRow Step 4
shTarget.Range(shTarget.Cells(i, 1), shTarget.Cells(i, 
 5)).Interior.Color = RGB(235, 235, 235)
shTarget.Range(shTarget.Cells(i, 7), shTarget.Cells(i, 
 8)).Interior.Color = RGB(235, 235, 235)
Next I
```

I get the color, but in an irregular manner. I put step 4 intentionally to show you what it looks like. For Step 2 almost all the rows are grey.

[image]

Comment: Is the coloring in the original data realy by interior.colorIndex or is it via conditional formatting?

Comment: It's based on colorIndex

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `shTarget.Range("A:E").ColorIndex = 15` is creating an error?

How about

```
For i = 2 To lRow Step 2

    With shTarget
    
        .Range(.Cells(i, 1), .Cells(i, 5)).Interior.ColorIndex = 15
        
    End With

Next i
```

instead? I can't see your image on my work PC but so I'm taking a guess :-)

In any case, you need `Interior` before `ColorIndex`.

Comment: I would also reset the clipboard to ```Application.CutCopyMode = False```.

Comment: Your example forks just for the first row unfortunately. I need something like:Cells(i & lRow, Step 2

Comment: You have to put it inside the loop. Look at my updated code.